# Folklore and mythology in The Witcher's bestiary

Tags: mythology, the-witcher, folklore

The Witcher's world has a **very** rich bestiarium.

For example the arts of a vampire:

- Higher Vampire
- Alpor
- Katakan
- Moola
- Bruxa
- Nosferat
- Ekimma
- Fleder
- Garkain
- Plumard

Or the Necrophages:

- Abaya
- Alghoul
- Devourer
- Drowner
- Foglet
- Ghoul
- ...

Which of those are The Witcher's native and which have a mythology background? Are those taken from polish folklore?

Is there any folklore text which describes the difference between, e.g. an *alpghoul* and a *ghoul*?

Comment: And which of these are made up by the Witcher games. Lots of monsters are mentioned briefly in the canon books, but never make an appearance there. Some are mentioned in the books but only make an appearance in the games. Others yet only exist in the games and not in the books. Sorting that mess alone out is quite a task, before you can even discuss which ones that are mythology/folklore and which ones that are invented by Sapkowski.